# How to preserve Google Photos geotag on download?

Tags: google-photos, geolocation

My photos are geotagged on google photos but when I download them, the geolocation information disappears. Is there anyway to download them with the geotag intact?

The photo I am trying this with was uploaded in original quality from my Samsung phone. I am accessing photos.google.com from the Chrome browser on my Mac (OS 10.13.5). Using `File > Get Info` on the file I see other metadata but not the coordinates. I experience the same issue with other photos too.

Comment: That's weird, I just tried that and my downloaded photo contains latitude and longitude. Are you downloading them from photos.google.com? Do you upload in high or original quality?

Comment: Good questions, I really should have included more info. I updated the post. What system and quality are you using when it works? Thanks arieljannai.

Comment: I'm also uploading in original quality (I don't know if that matters for that purpose), and downloading to Windows. Can you see the location on the web app? Do you see that on the downloaded photo details there's location details empty, or there isn't such property? You can also try to check with another program to get all the information on the photo, or re upload the downloaded photo to Google, to see if it will identifies they location online